# Sync al horizontal RecyclerView inside vertical list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview

Hi I have vertical list (Custom ArrayAdapter) where each element has a horizontal RecyclerView, to give me a table like format.
What I want to do is, if one row is scrolled horizontally, rest rows too should be. I tried putting them just inside horizontal scroll view and various tricks available, but got no luck.

If possible, I would also like this synchronization keeping first element fixed.
[image: Out of sync horizontal RecyclerViews inside a list]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make an instance of [`RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html). This instance will be common to **all** your horizontal recycler views. When `onScrolled( )` gets called, scroll all the views except the one on which this got called.

Comment: I can get dx and dy of the recycler view I scroll, but I get this in adapter of my parent listview's getView method (where I create this recycler view). So How Do I 1) Set this dx and dy to another recycler view, 2) Get rest of my recycler views while still in getView of parent listview

Comment: You'll have to store your `RecyclerView`s somewhere. Like in a set or list.

Answer (score 0):

Adding more to Little Child's answer, it was trickier than expected, I had to create a custom listener that was in my main Activity that was called by onScroll. This is because onScroll was in a getView method and did not get access to other views in listview, but my mainactivty could access them.

In my listadapter, I added

```
public interface RecycleListener {

    public void onScroll(int scroll_x);
}
```

Then in getView

```
    mRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            listener.onScroll(recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset());

        }
    });
```

and finally in MainActivity

```
dayAdapter.setRecycleListener(new DayAdapter.RecycleListener() {
        int busy = 0;
        @Override
        public void onScroll(int scroll_x)
        {
            if(busy == 1) return;
            busy = 1;
             for(int i = 0;i<days.size();i++)
            {
                    View view = lv.getChildAt(i);
                    if(view == null) continue;
                    RecyclerView r = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.timetable_row_recycler);
                    LinearLayoutManager  layoutManager =  ( LinearLayoutManager) r.getLayoutManager();
                    layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0-scroll_x);
            }
            busy = 0;
        }

    });
```

**Note** I found out that you can easily get scroll position by using `int scroll_x = recyclerView.computeHorizontalScrollOffset()` however there is no direct method to appy it back. The method `layoutManager.scrollToPosition(i)` scrolls to ith element and not the scroll position, so the only correct possible way is

```
layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0-scroll_x);
```

or (in case of custom layoutmanager)

```
((LinearLayoutManager) layoutManager).scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0-scroll_x);
```

We basically apply negative offset to the 0th position, so instead of scrolling to offset before 0th, it scrolls to our desired scroll_x.

**UPDATE** 
this worked but caused a lot of lag, so later I ended up switching to android.widget.TableLayout, and inserted rows (android.widget.TableRow) like I was trying with recyclerview.

Comment: that layoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0-scroll_x); will lag a lot if the rows have a lot of items like my case, i cant use that solution

Comment: @xanexpt, yup later I ended up switching to android.widget.TableLayout, and inserted android.widget.TableRow